# One time binding with Filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

When I try one-time binding with a filter here I'm getting and invalid date error:

```
<td>1w vol:</td>
<td>{{ :: edit_tag.termObject.vol }}</td>
<td>Added by:</td>
<td>{{ :: edit_tag.termObject.user }}</td>
<td>Timestamp:</td>
<td>{{ :: edit_tag.termObject.time | fromTimestamp:'MMM Do YYYY'}}</td>
```

[image]

---

The following works of course, however this date never changes, so I don't need to use 2-way binding with it. Is there a way to accomplish this?

`{{ edit_tag.termObject.time | fromTimestamp:'MMM Do YYYY'}}`

My filter if that helps:

```
.filter("fromTimestamp", function() {
    return function(timestamp, format) {
        return moment.unix(timestamp).format(format)
    }
});
```

Comment: does this code work for you - {{ edit_tag.termObject.time | fromTimestamp:'MMM Do YYYY'}} ?

Comment: Yes that works, but that is 2 way binding, trying to use 1 time binding here to avoid another `$watch`

Comment: Then you can inject 'moment' In your controller and create a function to format your value and still have one-way binging in the template

Comment: Ah true, I'm going to avoid using moment tho, to keep my app light since my filter is only 4 lines, 1 line compressed. However do you want to post your work around as the answer? I'll go ahead and check it, because that will be how you solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<td>{{ :: (edit_tag.termObject.time | fromTimestamp:'MMM Do YYYY')}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem indeed references this [issue 'One-time binding doesn't work with filters'](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8605). Where after some discussion the takeaway is:

> one time binding or not a given expression needs to stabilize. Your
>   filter makes it so the model never stabilizes hence the error.

So as a workaround you can use expression with `momentjs` in the controller to achieve this:

```
app.controller('test', function($scope, moment){
  //somehow we obtain edit_tag.termObject.time
  var desiredFomat = 'MMM Do YYYY';
  $scope.formattedTime = moment.unix(edit_tag.termObject.time).format(desiredFomat);
})
```

Then in your template:

```
<td>{{::formattedTime}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the working answer, Rusty's though is how I originally wanted to solve this.